# Deploy can't detect network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, decentralized-applications

I have build a smart contract with solidity, in this case I have compiled and test. I get 1 pass successfully waw. But when I deploy to BSC_TESTNET with command:

> npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network bsctest

I get error return: NETWORK_ERROR

[Watch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juXrv.png)

[And this my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDX36.png)

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.6.12",
  settings: {
    optimizer: true,
    runs: 200
  },
  networks: {
    dev: {
        url: "http://localhost:7545",
        gasPrice: 20,
        saveDeployments: true
    },
    bsctest: {
        url: "https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s2.binance.org:8545/",
        accounts: [process.env.PRIV_KEY],
        gasPrice: 10000000000,
        blockGasLimit: 1000000
    },
},
etherscan:{
  apiKey:process.env.API_KEY
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to re-check the API_KEY and you are accessing the .env files

You can use the following configuration.

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
// hardhat.config.js
const { mnemonic, apiKey } = require("./secrets.json");
// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.6.12",
      },
      {
        version: "0.5.16",
      },
      {
        version: "0.6.0",
      },
      {
        version: "0.4.18",
      },
      {
        version: "0.6.6",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 1000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  networks: {
    dev: {
      url: "http://localhost:8545",
      gasPrice: 50000000000,
      saveDeployments: true,
    },
    bsctest: {
      url: "https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s2.binance.org:8545/",
      accounts: { mnemonic: mnemonic },
      gasPrice: 10000000000,
      blockGasLimit: 1000000,
    },
    // bsc: {
    //     url: "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/",
    //     accounts: [process.env.PRIV_KEY],
    //     gasPrice: 5100000000,
    //     blockGasLimit: 1000000
    // }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: apiKey,
  },
};
```

Make sure you are having a secret.json in the directory with following property

```
{
  "url": "https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545",
  "apiKey": "",
  "mnemonic": "",
  "key": ""
}
```